# When using inheritance is it necessary to "#include" the header file of child's parent class. C++

Tags: c++, header-files, multiple-inheritance

I'm working on a multiple inheritance project in C++. I have separate files for class definitions (.h) and implementations (.cpp). Since this is the first time I've used inheritance in C++ (the rest of our assignments have been in C#) somethings are a little unclear.

Do I need to `#include "parent.h"`  in `child.cpp`, or is it sufficient to have defined the inheritance relationship in `child.h` ie:

```
class child : parent 
{ 
     // child class definition
};
```

I was warned by an automated prompt that this might be a subjective question, so let me be explicit: I'm asking if this is a *functional requirement* for the inheritance to work properly, not if it's "good form" or anything along those lines.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Question**

> Do I need to `#include "parent.h"` in `child.cpp`, or is it sufficient to have defined the inheritance relationship in `child.h`

**Answer**

> No, you don't need to `#include "parent.h"` in `child.cpp`. It is sufficient to `#include "child.h"` in `child.cpp`. The contents of `"parent.h"` are available in `child.cpp` since `child.h` already has `#include "parent.h"`

Answer (score 2):

Just in case this isn't clear:
`#include` does a simple textual copy, there is no additional logic involved.

So no, it is not necessary. However the reason is not that you have defined the inheritance relation ship, but because
`#include "parent.h"` in `child.h` already copies the text of `parent.h` into `child.h` and then `#include child.h` in `child.cpp`, copies the whole text (including the part from `parent.h`) there. Another include would be redundant, and without the include guards it would even cause compiler errors.

Btw.:Conceptually, your compiler doesn't see the headerfiles as separate entities. It sees only a single textstream, which is produced by starting with the cpp file and then executing (recursively) all #include directives.